# Hyper-V: virtual machine in a virtual machine

Tags: hyper-v

is it possible to create a virtual machine in a virtual machine?

Let's say I have a virtual server with SCVMM installed and I would like to create a new VMS in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. Virtualization in hardware - the only type Hyper-V supports - is only supported once by the processor.

The edge cases for that are anyway more the "I am too cheap to rent a second VM" people because otherwise tzere are ZERO reasons to do that. In your case for example - there is no, absolutely no, reason to create the machine in the SCVMM virtual machine. You can create it on the host.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, there is no reason to do that. Unless you are working for a company where to get a "real" machine takes forever.

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek Still no reason. As in - MS does not care (as do most supplies) about accumulated business incompetence. I knew trading floors running "not approoved" HPC clusters under desks for that reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can run a VM inside a VM. It's done often for various reasons.
And it depends on the hypervisor being used.

Have a look at the article below. These are instructions on how to set up a VM inside a VM
"How to Install Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 in VMware Workstation (works for Windows Server 2008 too)"
http://hyper-v-backup.backupchain.com/how-to-install-hyper-v-server-2012-r2-in-vmware-workstation-works-for-windows-server-2008-too/

You can use Windows XP for example, install VMware Workstation, then create a VM, patch it as shown in article, boot and install Windows Server 2012 and then create VMs inside Server 2012. No problem

Comment: "no problem" except it's a *wholly unsupported configuration*. As a site [for professionals](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) we generally don't tend to advocate configurations that the vendor has said are not supported - when things break and your vendor won't help you the sysadmin who implemented the "solution" is the one left holding the bag.

Comment: The guy asked "is it possible". He didn't say "should I do it". Naturally sometimes configurations may be interesting, useful, and sometimes unsupported. That's life. I don't think a sysadmin should be prohibited from trying new things. At his/her own risk of course. It's up to the sysadmin to use tools responsibly. We all agree. No problem :)